# Existence of geodesic by heat flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

In Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, for proving the existence of geodesic , we consider a heat flow 1.6.2 and 1.6.3

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

How to get the last two lines? This is integrate , the normal coordinate only can used in a point not a neiborghood .
$$
\int -2g_{ij}u^i_{ss}u_t^j-2g_{ij,k}u^k_su^i_tu^j_s+g_{ij,k}u_t^ku^i_su^j_s \\
=\int  -2g_{ij}u^i_{ss}u_t^j-g_{ij,k}u^k_su^i_tu^j_s
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal coordinates are not being used, as should be clear by the presence of metric derivatives. Just substitute $u^i_{ss} = u^i_{t} - \Gamma^i_{jk} u^j_s u^k_s$ from the original PDE and use the coordinate expression for the Christoffel symbols in terms of the derivatives of the metric.

I'd warn you that the last part of Jost's proof (Step 5) is incorrect - here he *does* integrate by parts while using normal coordinates, so he forgets a curvature term. You actually need $M$ to have non-positive curvature for this result (the strong convergence to a geodesic as $t \to \infty$) to hold - otherwise there are counterexamples, see e.g. [this paper](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/parker/ChoiParkerGeodesics.pdf).

Comment: Where is the curvature term in Step 5. I compute it ,there is a term contain $\partial_m\Gamma_{jk}^i$

Comment: Could you detail write the Step 5 (compute $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}E(u(~,t))$) ?  I can't get the curvature term .

Comment: If you use covariant derivatives instead then you have to exchange derivatives $u^i_{sst} \to u^i_{sts}$ because you integrate by parts, so you pick up a curvature term of the form $R_{stj}{}^i u^j_s$. The coordinate method should also work - you should get $\partial \Gamma$ and $\Gamma \Gamma$ terms that you can collect together in to the usual coordinate formula for the curvature tensor.

Comment: It is unfortunate that this heat flow is recently added. I can't find it in my (3rd edition) copy.