# Convexity of energy of geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, heat-equation, geodesic

In 34 page of Jost's [Riemannian geometry and geometric analysis](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=131A6675E500DE298E231E6629890289). How to compute the $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}E$ ? Seemly, there are some wrong in the below calculate according this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933089/existence-of-geodesic-by-heat-flow/1933637?noredirect=1#comment3972746_1933637).But I fail to get the results.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: As Anthony said, in the last line of your first calculation, you need to change $u^i_{sst}$ to $u^i_{sts}$ so that you do integration by part. But that will give you a Ricci term, by Ricci identity.

Comment: @JohnMa just changes $t$ and $s$,  but Ricci term is needed only when change two parameter of space. Are you sure ? Besides, I can't calculate out it , although I agree there is a Ricci term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Professor Jost is obviously a big fan of coordinate calculations. If you like a coordinate free calculation: Note the heat flow is

$$\tag{1} \frac{\partial }{\partial t} = \nabla_{\frac{\partial }{\partial s}} \frac{\partial }{\partial s}, $$

then for $E(u_t) = \frac 12\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\| \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right\|^2 ds $, we have

$$\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt} E(u_t) &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\| \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right\|^2 ds \\
&= \int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right\rangle ds\\
&= \int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right\rangle ds\\
&= -\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right\rangle ds.
\end{split}$$

(Note that the term $\int_{\mathbb S^1}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \right\rangle ds$ vanishes by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus). Using the heat flow equation $(1)$, we have

$$ \frac{d}{dt} E(u_t) = - \int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds.$$

Then

$$\begin{split}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2} E(u_t) &= -\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds \\
&=-2\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds \\
&= -2\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) \text{ again} \\
&= -2 \int_{\mathbb S^1} \left(\left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle + \left\langle R\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial s} , \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle\right)ds \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)\\
&= 2\int_{\mathbb S^1}  \left\langle \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds-2 \int_{\mathbb S^1}\left\langle R\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial s} , \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds \\
&= 2\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\| \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\|^2 ds -2 \int_{\mathbb S^1}\left\langle R\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial s} , \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds 
\end{split}$$

where in $(*)$ we used the definition of curvature tensor and the fact that $\left[ \frac{\partial }{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right] =0$. Thus this term does not really have a sign, unless the space has nonpositive sectional curvature.

Comment: For your $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} = \nabla_{\frac{\partial }{\partial s}} \frac{\partial }{\partial s}$ , I understand it by $\partial_t u =\nabla_{\partial_su}\partial_su $, then $u_t=\nabla_{u_s^ie_i}u^j_se_j=u^i_su^j_s\Gamma_{ij}^ke_k+u_{ss}^je_j$ , is right ?

Comment: Yes, since $$\nabla_{\frac{\partial }{\partial s}} (u_s^j e_j) = u^j_{ss} e_j + u^j_s \nabla_{\frac{\partial }{\partial s}} e_j =  u^j_{ss} e_j + u^j_s u^i_s \nabla_{e_i} e_j = u^j_{ss} e_j + u^j_s u^i_s \Gamma_{ij}^ke_k. $$ @lanse7pty

Comment: For getting $\nabla_{\partial_t}\partial_s=\nabla_{\partial_s}\partial_t$ , I conpute the $\nabla_{\partial_t}\partial_s=\nabla_{u_t^ie_i}u_s^je_j=u_t^iu_s^j\Gamma_{ij}^ke_k+u_{st}^je_j$ and $\nabla_{\partial_s}\partial_t=\nabla_{u_t^ie_i}u_s^je_j=u_t^iu_s^j\Gamma_{ij}^ke_k+u_{ts}^je_j$ , because $u_{ts}=u_{st}$, so $\nabla_{\partial_t}\partial_s=\nabla_{\partial_s}\partial_t$ , but seemly ,it is  a little dull. Whether there is easy way ?

Comment: Just use that the lie bracket between the two is zero and the torsion free condition. @lanse7pty

Comment: Why Lie bracket is zero ?

Comment: Because partial derivative commutes. @lanse7pty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45839/discussion-between-lanse7pty-and-john-ma).

Comment: My result is $= 2\int_{\mathbb S^1} \left\| \nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial s}}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\|^2 ds  +2 \int_{\mathbb S^1}\left\langle R\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial s} , \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\frac{\partial}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right\rangle ds 
$ , because $R(\partial_s,\partial_t)\partial_s=\nabla_s\nabla_t\partial_s-\nabla_t\nabla_s\partial_s$ ,seemly ,you have a error in (*)

Comment: We are using different convention. My $R$ is negative or your $R$. @lanse7pty